# Dajngo: Как перенаправить пользователя на прошлую страницу после регистрации?

Tags: python, django

Для покупки товара есть 4 шага. Если пользователь не зарегистрирован, то после второго шага его должно перенаправить на страницу регистрации. А когда он зарегистрируется, то его должно перенести на третий шаг. Как можно реализовать данную логику? (В моем случае после регистрации его переносит на главную страницу, а должно на третий шаг)
[image: Шаги покупки]

views.py ( Это обработчик второго шага )

```py
class NewTrackingSubscriptions(DataMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profiles/new-tracking-subscription.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('login_user')
        return render(request, 'profiles/new-tracking-subscription.html', self.get_context_data())
```

views.py ( Это обработчик регистрации пользователя )

```py
class SignupUser(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=self.request.POST['email'],
                                              first_name=self.request.POST['first_name'],
                                              last_name=self.request.POST['last_name'],
                                              password=self.request.POST['password'])
        user.save()
        login(self.request, user)

        return redirect('index')
```

Comment: Сохраняйте страницу возврата в параметрах вызова страницы регистрации. Либо можно использовать заголовок браузера referer.

Comment: А можно поподробнее, как сохранить в параметрах, или же что такое referer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контексте для формы регистрации передавайте параметр *return_to_url* любым из способов.

В форме добавьте поле

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="{{ return_to_url }}">
```

**Либо** можно поступить даже вот так:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return_to"  value="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}">
```

В таком случае будет возвращаться всегда на тут страницу, с которой форма была вызвана. Учтите, что если например форма окажется не валидной хотя  бы раз - редирект будет на саму форму.  Так что лучше первый способ с "ручной" передачей контекста.

Тогда у Вас будет такая views:

```
class SignupUser(CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'account/signup.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = CustomUser.objects.create_user(email=self.request.POST['email'],
                                              first_name=self.request.POST['first_name'],
                                              last_name=self.request.POST['last_name'],
                                              password=self.request.POST['password'])
        user.save()
        login(self.request, user)

        return redirect(request.POST['return_to']))
```

Comment: Я не особо понимаю для чего нужны инпуты? И будет ли это работать, если пользователь может войти и зарегестрироваться?

Comment: тут input hidden. Вместо него можете использовать например url-encoded параметр.